# Cleaning up dynamo DB table through jenkins

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-dynamodb

I have a very restrictive policy on QA environment's aws in my company. I need a way to clean up dynamo db tables using jenkins. One of the thing I could think of using aws cli commands but I could not find a way to wipe out the content of dynamo db by just using aws cli. If there was a command I could have easily done it using aws cli commands on Jenkins. Any insights would be really helpful.

Answer (score 2):

We had the same problem. Deleting bulk records is time consuming, costly proceess.

We delete the table and recreate it and recreate the data as needed.
I have not seen anything special with jenkins except running the aws cli shell script.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of concerns in terms, if you allow Jenkins to directly access DynamoDB and delete content, make sure to grant fine grained access control with IAM policies given to the AWS CLI execution to restrict permission to delete the data in particular tables.

Another approach is to use a SNS trigger (HTTP, Email & etc.) by Jenkins where it will run a Lambda function to delete the content. Here you do not need to give AWS DynamoDB Access Permission to your Jenkins Server and Script can be version controlled and managed outside Jenkins.

You can also consider using [DynamoDB Local](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBLocal.html) for Testing purposes.

> The downloadable version of DynamoDB lets you write and test
>   applications without accessing the DynamoDB web service. Instead, the
>   database is self-contained on your computer. When you're ready to
>   deploy your application in production, you can make a few minor
>   changes to the code so that it uses the DynamoDB web service.